# open a link in different browser java swing

Tags: java, swing, browser

How do i open a link in different browser in java swing??

I've read this article :
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/openBrowser.html

This is opening in my default browser. But when I want to open in a different browser

it gives an error message: "Cannot run program "which": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
"

Comment: Just a clue as to your exception - 'which' is a *nix command line tool used to search your path.  So your example code thinks you are running on a *nix machine...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, to open a link in the user's default browser you should really be using the more modern approach:

```
String url = "www.stackoverflow.com";
Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.browse(url);
```

**No need to mess about with working out what OS you are running on** (as your linked example attempts to do).  Far better to let `java.awt.Desktop` take care of finding an appropriate browser or application to open the URL (see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) for more details).

There's also a part of the API that gracefully handles permissions and 'unusual' OS setups.  If there is the possibility that your code will run under a restricted security policy or on a platform that may not have a browser, then you can check up front rather than wait for the exception from the call to `browse`.

```
// check if java.awt.Desktop is available on the current platform
java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported();

// check the current platform and security policy will let you browse to a url
Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE);
```

Comment: And by doing this you will open the link with the default browser, which is the browser the user of that system wants to use